# Customize Map´s Layout

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, route-me

I'm developing an application that displays maps without using MapKit IOS.

Therefore I am using **[Route-Me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me)**. However need to create a few maps with colors according to the design of my application.

Is there any way to do this without being use the **MapBox** platform, which requires a payment at some point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely get what you are asking for. You can generate map tiles from the OpenStreetMap data and configure their appearance, when generating the tiles. You can put these map tiles on a server and display them using route-me. You can as well generate a sqlite database from the tiles and put this database onto the phone together with your application.

Comment: can i generate an map tile from all the planet??

Comment: You can generate tiles for the whole planet. Map tiles are organised as quad trees. That is, if you completely zoom out, the world is shown on a single tile. If you zoom one level in, the world is displayed on four tiles of the same size and so on. Please note that I have no practical experience with generating tiles but there are several tools. You might want to ask at the route-me google group to get in contact with people with more experience.

Comment: thanks for the answer... i just wanted to change for example the color of the streets, i imagine it could be more simple... thanks